# Datagridview - Skip header

Tags: vb.net

I'm adding data from catia to datagridview. A portion of code where I'm having trouble is shown below. When I bind the datatable to datagridview, the data gets pasted starting from the header and I'm not sure how to skip the header and start from row 1. Appreciate any help. Thank you. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfJAx.jpg)

```
    Dim txtLines1 As New List(Of String())
    _StringList.ToList().ForEach(Sub(x) txtLines1.Add(x.Split(New Char() {";"})))

    If txtLines1.Count > 0 Then
        txtLines1.Item(5).ToList.ForEach(Sub(x) txtDataTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(x.ToString)))

        txtLines1.RemoveAt(1)
    End If

    If txtLines1.Count > 0 Then
                txtLines1.ToList.ForEach(Sub(x) txtDataTable.Rows.Add(x.ToArray))
            End If
```

Comment: In large part it looks like a debugging issue: something is going wrong in that code but since we dont have the data there is little help we can offer. It does seem like you could skip that second step and use the interim list as a DataSource. Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

You are using the values in Item 5 (the 6th one) of your list as your column name.  That is what is displaying there.  For each column in the data grid, you could update it to give it a more meaningful name.

```
txtLines1.Item(5).ToList.ForEach(Sub(x) txtDataTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(x.ToString)))
```

This is a way to give it a meaningful name:

txtDataTable.Columns(4).ColumnName = "5th Column"
   txtDataTable.Columns(4).Caption = "5th Column"

Based on this 2nd set of code below, it then removes the 2nd item from the list, before adding the items to a DataTable.  Not sure why you would remove the 2nd item.

```
    txtLines1.RemoveAt(1)
End If

If txtLines1.Count > 0 Then
            txtLines1.ToList.ForEach(Sub(x) txtDataTable.Rows.Add(x.ToArray))
End If
```

So your grid results display:
The 6th item as the column names

Followed by as the data:

- 1st Item
- 3rd List item (You removed the 2nd one - Item(1))
- 4th List item
- 5th List Item
- 6th List Item
- ...